# PHP - Advanced Permutations

Tags: php

Best to all, as the title says, I have a problem with the permutations of arrays.

Most systems use arrays to exchange all, but I need one that is progressive, I give an example:

The array contains the values: "one, two, three, four, number"

The exchangers I saw from the first iteration combined 5 values.

But what I want is to fence one by one, for example:

number one
one Number
number four
four Number
....
a four number three

Sorry for my bad English, I'm using Google translator, I'm from Argentina =)

Comment: Do you mean i want to print permutations of all numbers in an array..Something like 1 21 321 4321

Comment: add your code here, which you have tried